# What does MaterialPageRoute with the context?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

What does **MaterialPageRoute** do with `context`?
And what is the purpose of **builder:** here.

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text("Second Route"),
                    ),
                    body: Center(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Text('Go back!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every state of widget required some context to perform some work, direct or indirect context should be used.

The [BuildContext] for a particular widget can change location over time as the widget is moved around the tree. Because of this, values returned from
the methods in this class should not be cached beyond the execution of a
single synchronous function.

**Example:**

In the question code for back navigation used `Navigator.pop(context);`  so it will be running in a separate state, not the build(contex) from where navigation starts

Comment: @Muhammad Sarmad: hope you got the idea? how does it work?

Comment: Nope. I think I need someone who sits in front of me and explain using pen and paper 